# The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and 'NuGetApi2.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am trying to serialize object on the fly into immediate window by using

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
```

However I am getting following error

> The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and 'NuGetApi2.dll'

It happens when `.dll` that is not referenced in project is placed into `bin` folder next to other `.dll` that is referenced in that project and has same library within (in this case `Newtonsoft.Json` in `NuGetApi2.dll` which ins't referenced in project)

**Why do I only get this exception when using immediate/debug window an not when it is compiled code?** (When its compiled it works fine since compiler is using dll that is referenced in the project)

**How do I tell Visual Studio which `.dll` to use (preferably without having to stop program from running)?**
One obvious way is to delete `.dll` that isn't referenced in project,.... What I am asking for: is there a way to tell it which `dll` to use via code from `Immediate window`....

**UPDATE:** solution to reproduce bug can be found here:

https://github.com/liufa/Temp

Solution is zipped in `WebApplication1.7z`, I used MVC app, to reproduce add breakpoint in `HomeController`, `Index` Method and when it gets hit paste `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sfdsdfsdf");` into immediate window in Visual Studio.

Code in project looks following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sdfsdf");
#if DEBUG    
        var y = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sfssesss");
#endif
        return View(); //put breakpoint here then into immediate window paste Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sdfsdf"); and you should get the error.
    }
```

Comment: Where does `NuGetApi2.dll` come from? My guess is that `JsonConvert` is internal inside that - which means the compiler will normally ignore it, but allow access in the debug window.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi Jon, If talking folders they both are coming from `/bin`. if talking nugets Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert -  `Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and NuGetApi2.dll comes from folder called `ThirdParty` where it sits with other `.dll`s like `Mindscape.LightSpeed.dll` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo` and others. My guess is that `NuGetApi2.dll` sits there as support for 3rd party dlls that rely on having JSON and other commonly used libs....

Comment: But where did you create that folder from? If we're going to be able to reproduce the problem, we could do with that DLL... There's no obvious place online where that comes from. (I could *probably* reproduce it manually with a hand-written library, but it would be nice to do reproduce your exact problem.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Folder with dlls been there when I came (got assigned to project) :) I will post dll somewhere in a moment... Gimme a sec

Comment: Rather than that, I'd ask someone else where they've come from - and I'd recommend keeping a document alongside them to make sure it's always obvious :)

Comment: @JonSkeet https://github.com/liufa/Temp here you go NuGetApi2.dll.

Comment: Hmm... trying that DLL in a project that also has Json.NET gives a compile-time error for me. Interesting. Do you also *have* a reference to `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` in your project? (Basically, I can't reproduce this - I either get a compile-time error or no intermediate window error. Can you show some code that's using `Json.NET` in your project? I'd like to be able to reproduce this...)

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi, sorry for delay had a meeting and second one in a minute, I will try to create reproducable solution and put it on github, in couple of hours or so...

Comment: @JonSkeet Done, solution zipped in `WebApplication1.7z`, I used mvc app, just add breakpoint in HomeController Index and paste `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sfdsdfsdf");` into immediate window. One thing I was unable to do is to have in code something like `var x = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);` and build it -errors with unable to figure out dll, which I don't get in solution I am working on. BTW it turns out that these `.dll` from ThirdParty folder are being copied manually by console app when solution runs :) We live in a weird world....

Comment: While putting a zip file on the web is a start, it would be much better if you could try to reduce this to a [mcve]. I'll have a look now though...

Comment: The code you've provided never uses `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` as far as I can see.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have updated the code, it didn't build at first, but now it does for whatever reason I have uploaded new version

Comment: Well your project doesn't have a reference to `NuGetApi2.dll`. As soon as you add one, it fails to compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yep, to reproduce it don't add dll to project just run with `NuGetApi2.dll` sitting in bin without being referenced in project, and it will fail in immediate window.

Comment: Well why have you got it there at all? Basically you're in a very strange situation, copying in assemblies which weren't present at compile time. (So no wonder "When its compiled it works fine"...) I would strongly suggest you get yourself out of having such an odd deployment infrastructure - and use a DLL which *doesn't* embed another assembly publicly...

Comment: @JonSkeet not the first time to see something like this (I am sure you too could write a code horror book) :) but yeah still if dll isn't referenced one would expect it not to affect the project and yet it gets loaded and breaks things...

Comment: I suspect that's the debugger trying to be helpful for you. All the more reason to spend as little time in the debugger as possible...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks Jon, sorry if I wasted your time with this. I didn't have this much info when originally posting question, and it could have been something that happens commonly.... BTW `#if debug` does not cause the error ...

Answer (score -1):

By default .Net web sites load all of the assemblies in the bin folder at startup. You can change this behavior by modifying the web.config file, in which case you need to list out the assemblies you want loaded instead.

Here is an example that only loads version 1.0.0.0 of `MySite.dll`

```
<system.web>
  <compilation>
    <assemblies>
      <remove assembly="*" />
      <add assembly="MySite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

If you only load the assemblies you need and don't load the NuGetApi2 assembly this should solve your problem

Comment: Tried the following `<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
      <assemblies>
        <remove assembly="NuGetApi2, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>` and it still gives same message (`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject("sfsdf");
The type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll' and 'NuGetApi2.dll'`)

Comment: Of course it didn't work, you didn't do what I suggested. Your remove instruction does nothing because that dll wasn't in the configuration to begin with.